# Bootstrap 4 - Dropdown not working properly with mobile menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

On all devices, the navbar is working properly but I don't know why, on mobile device, when I click on the avatar (displaying a toggle menu), the brand image is moving ...

[gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjMaB.gif)

ERB code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-brand">
  <%= link_to songs_path, class: "navbar-brand" do %>
    <%= image_tag "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnzggrpqe/image/upload/v1614710692/logo_kf5loy.png", class: "brand-logo" %>
  <% end %>

  <div id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <%= image_tag "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnzggrpqe/image/upload/v1614709216/song_book_user_2_ivhkgt.png", class: "avatar dropdown-toggle", id: "navbarDropdown", data: { toggle: "dropdown" }, 'aria-haspopup': true, 'aria-expanded': false %>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <%= link_to "Dashboard", user_root_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
            <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
          </div>
        </li>
      <% else %>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <%= image_tag "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnzggrpqe/image/upload/v1614709216/song_book_user_2_ivhkgt.png", class: "avatar dropdown-toggle", id: "navbarDropdown", data: { toggle: "dropdown" }, 'aria-haspopup': true, 'aria-expanded': false %>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
        </div>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS associated :

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}


.navbar-brand .navbar-collapse {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.navbar-brand .navbar-brand img {
  width: 200px;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.avatar {
  position: sticky;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.avatar:hover {
  border: solid 2px;
  border-color: rgb(122, 193, 226);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  display: none;
}
```

Does someone have an idea ? (I know, so many questions about this problem...) Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution :)
It was indeed a css issue - I change the navbar-brand "align-items" from center to flex-start and then decrease the width of the logo and it works !

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of the menu your opening: How large is it?

If you add that width to the actual brand image, it might be too large and start a new line.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to delete the brand image but unfortunatly, I got the same behaviour for the avatar - the size is 160 x 82 px